# How to use Metadata API to search which field is used in validation rules

Tags: api, metadata

I want a solution to understand how we use metadata API to get a list of validation rules in which a particular field api is present

Comment: Please review this reference:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28877/how-to-know-if-a-custom-field-is-referenced-in-workflow-or-validation-rule-using#answer-28878

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use **Metadata API** for your purposes. You can use **Tooling API**.
First, you can query all Validation Rules in your org with only Id field to create a set if its Ids:

```
/services/data/v45.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+ValidationRule
```

Then you can query  Validation Rule with **Metadata** and **FullName**  fields for each available Validation Rule Id because when we're retrieving results with **Metadata** or **FullName** fields, the query qualifications must specify ***no more than one row for retrieval***:

```
/services/data/v45.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Metadata,FullName+FROM+ValidationRule+WHERE+Id='IdFromOurSet'
```

Metadata field of each returned Validation Rule record contains text field **errorConditionFormula** in which you can search your desirable field API name.

For more details please read [Tooling API | ValidationRule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_validationrule.htm)

Comment: hey Oleh, I have already found the solution using Tooling API now working with Metadata API

Comment: hi @Gitika, can you pls detail your solution? I am trying to query the errorconditionformula field, and am unable to get the results for all the rules at a single go.